# Как поймать и запретить редирект?

Tags: redirect, php, javascript

Есть iframe, в котором с другого сайта отображается информация.
В данном iframe используется авторизация стороннего сайта, но при логауте происходит редирект с моего сайта на их сайт index.php.

Как можно с помощью, наверное, js (или чего-то еще) понять, что произошел редирект, и вернуть пользователя на предыдущую страницу.

Comment: @jonsel, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш JS не будет работать в ифрейме, как вариант попробуйте грузить ифрейм, как показано ниже, например, если вы хотите вернуться на страницу `index.php`:

`<iframe src="index.php?url=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404966">`